# Monte carlo portfolio risk simulation

Tags: risk-management, monte-carlo, models, simulations, normal-distribution

My objective is to show the distribution of a portfolio's expected utilities via random sampling.

The utility function has two random components. The first component is an expected return vector which is shocked by a random Gaussian variable ($ER$). The shock shifts the location parameter of the return distribution.

The second random component is a covariance matrix which is multiplied by a random scalar $S$. The scalar is drawn from a normal random variable, centered on $1$, where the variance of $S$ corresponds to our uncertainty in whether volatility increases or decreases.

My initial plan was to take separate draws of the $S$ and $EV$ and simply calculate the utility. However, clearly these random variables are not conditionally independent. In particular, research suggests that when volatility is increasing (i.e. $S > 1$), the  expected returns distribution has a lower overall mean. Or, if volatility is contracting rapidly it is likely that the expected returns distribution has a higher mean.

In other words, I should be sampling from the joint distribution of $EV$ and $S$ as opposed to the marginal distributions of $EV$ and $S$ separately.

**What's a good technique to estimate and sample these random variables from their joint distribution?** The "correct" approach I can think of involves defining a set of states, estimating the transition probabilities between state pairs, and sampling $EV$ and $S$ conditional on random draws of a third state variable. Seems like overkill!

A crude variation of this would be to build a transition matrix such as [ High Vol to High Vol, Low to Low, Low to High Vol, High to Low Vol ] where  the location and scale parameters ($ER$ and $S$) are informed by an "expert" (i.e. casual inspection of the data).

Are there other techniques that I may be missing that provide a solid "80/20 rule" solution for sampling from this joint distribution, or is state-space (markov models and the like) the only way to go? For example, perhaps there is a non-parametric technique to estimate the relationship between these two variables.

Comment: "research suggests that when volatility is increasing (i.e. 'S' is > 1), the expected returns distribution has a lower overall mean" if you assume a diffusion process of the sort $dS=mSdt+sSdz$ which has a mean of $m-s^2/2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since both $ER$ and $S$ are gaussian random, why not just assume their dependence is captured by their covariance, and make your draws from the bivariate normal distribution?  It is hard to construct any *other* way of making two marginal gaussians cointegrated.

Even if the variables were not gaussian, you would probably find yourself relating them using a gaussian copula anyway.

Comment: Right on +1. Question is how to estimate the covariance. Perhaps using a non-parametric bootstapping approach -- or using the mean of rolling historical returns, and the sum of elements of a rolling covariance matrix and estimating the covariance of these pairs?

Comment: I think the best way to go about this is to fit a gaussian copula to capture the dependency between the marginal distributions. This is identical to saying the dependence is captured by their covariance. Thanks!